# Is it possible to send an array in a php header (like you can with a form)?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make a dynamically sized form for a web-page I am creating! I have had no issue passing the information needed to the 'action' page through a form (including two arrays), by setting the name of all dynamically created forms to be `name[i]`.
To get the data from the array in the 'action' file, I use the code below, and it works fine:

```
$_POST['name'][$i]
```

However, I wish to return the information to the form if there is an error with any of it, and the way I am doing this is with headers.

```
 header("Location: ../originalPage.php?error=error&someValue=".$someValue."&someArray[]=".$someArray);
 exit();
```

Is there anything I need to change for this to return something other than `Array()`?
Clearly the header is using the `$_GET` method rather than the `form`'s `$_POST` method, but why can I only send the array one way?!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So `$someArray` is itself an array? You can not concatenate arrays into strings like that, that will always only result in the _word_ “Array”. You would need to access and append the individual, scalar values one by one.

Comment: But the real _proper_ solution to your problem is likely https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @CBroe Yes, `$someArray` is itself an array, and I wish to place this into the header as a single parameter, just like I did with the form to begin with. If the only way to do that is to append them individually, that's fine, I was just hoping there may be another way! Thanks for the help already though!

Comment: I just pointed you to what the proper way of handling this would be, did I not? You create the proper _data structure_ that contains all the parameters you want to append to the URL query string, and then you let the mentioned function handle the rest.

Comment: @CBroe s method is pretty easy and smart. it will take you about 2 minutes to change your header, and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you try to concatenate your `array` to a string, but that does not happen in the way you would prefer. You could convert your `array` into JSON, like this:

```
 ../originalPage.php?error=error&someValue=".$someValue."&someArray[]=".json_encode($someArray));
```

Read more about [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) by clicking on the link.